# What is the probability that a player will receive a red card over the course of the season

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the probability that a goalkeeper will get *at least* one red card over the course of the season.

There are on average 2.75 red cards (in total for all goalkeepers) per season.

I define an event as one goalkeeper playing a match. There are 20 different goalkeepers. There are 380 matches in a season and 2 goalkeepers in each match, so 760 events in total.

That means that the probability of a goalkeeper getting sent off in any given match is

2.75 / 760 = 0.003618..

Each goalkeeper will play 38 matches per season, so the probability of a goalkeeper getting at least one red card in a season is

1 - (1 - (2.75 / 760))^38 = 0.128..

So roughly 13%, this seems quite high to me and I have no idea if what I have done is correct (or even possible to calculate with the given assumptions) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Actually your probability doesn't seem that unreasonable when you consider that (approximately) $3$ red cards will be given out to $20$ goalkeepers over the course of the season.  It is of course possible that some goalkeeper(s) (the ones with more temper?) will get more than one red card.

Comment: According to the Poisson model in my answer, the probability of _more than one_ red card for a goalkeeper per season is 0.0086 (assuming all goalkeepers have equal tempers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say there are, on average, 2.75 red-card events for all 20 goalkeepers.
If all goalkeepers participate equally and are equally likely to
get red cards, then the *average* rate of events for each individual goalkeeper per season is $\lambda = 2.75/20 = 0.1375.$ (I do not
follow this game avidly, so I hope I have got that much right.)

A reasonable model is that the number $X$ of events for any one
goalkeeper is $X \sim Pois(\lambda).$ Then $P(X = 0) = e^{-0.1375}$
and $P(X > 0) = 1 - e^{-0.1375} = 0.1284.$

Your terminology tends to confuse *probability* and *average*,
but you have good intuition and essentially the right answer.
(It seems to me your underlying model is binomial, which
is well approximated by Poisson for small 'event' probabilities
and large numbers of 'trials".